# Good OS (gOS) instalation from USB key

Tags: usb, boot, usb-flash-drive, bootloader

I would like to install Good OS from USB key.

I have found a nice instructions http://www.pendrivelinux.com/usb-gos-install-from-windows/.

Everything is OK while USB key is being prepared. But when I am trying to boot from that USB key I get the following error:

```
"no bootable partition in table"
```

It seems like USB key is not prepared properly ...

**How can I install gOS from USB key?**

Comment: make sure the usb keys is properly formated in the correct format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

Windows Vista and Windows 7 have a UAC feature, so you have manually run "makeboot.bat" **on your USB key** with administrative rights (right click, "run as administrator") after initial USB key setup ("fixgOS2.bat").

Answer (score 0):

If you have the actual .ISO file of the gOS, you can use netbootin (under Windows or Linux) to make a USB key bootable from this ISO. It basically transfers all files,as well as the boot record into the USB key to make it bootable. You will likely not have the same boot menu as if you were booting from actual CD or the ISO, but the options will be there so you can boot it. Of course, your netbook must be able to boot from USB first, or you need to be able to select the USB storage device at startup time.

I do this all the time on my ASUS EeePC netbook, and it works like a charm. I found out that some of the USB keys may not be bootable. for some strange reason.

Just use Google for UNETBOOTIN and you will be able to get the latest version. AS I sais, it can be user under Windows (without install) or under Linux.

JF